# Can $p^{\frac{p}{q}}$ and $q^{\frac{p}{q}}$ both be rational with $p,q$ relatively prime and $p,q \neq 0$ and $p,q \neq 1$

Tags: number-theory

Can $p^{\frac{p}{q}}$ and $q^{\frac{p}{q}}$ both be rational with $p,q$ as integers relatively prime and $p,q \neq 0$ and $p,q \neq 1$? I think so, but I am not able to prove it...

Answer (score 1):

Since *p* and *q* are coprime, this is tantamount to asking if $~\sqrt[\Large q]q\in$ **Q** for $q\neq1$, which is obviously false.

---

$q=q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_n^{a_n}$, with $q_k$ prime. The smallest prime is $2$. Then $a_k~p$ must be a multiple of *q* for all *k*, otherwise $\sqrt[\Large q]{q^p}$ is irrational. But $\gcd(p,q)=1~=>~q|a_k~=>~q\ge2^q.~$ Contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention $q^{\frac{p}{q}}$...

Comment: I meant $q^{\frac{p}{q}}$, but I'm sorry, I don't see why this is a trivial thing.

Comment: @Rummelluff: Better?

Answer (score 0):

$9^{9/2} = 3^{9}$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Pick two prime numbers $q,r$ and construct an example using $p=r^q$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention $q^{\frac{p}{q}}$...